# View GRIB files with Squid - Wine

Tags: wine, weather

Squid is a program written for Windows 7 and 10 for viewing GRIB files and routing by Great Circle. I tried to run the program with Wine, but the program freezes after loading. Can anybody help me?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Why are you using a Windows apps when there are native ones, like **zyGrib GRIB file viewer**?

Comment: @CelticWarrior Please post that comment as an answer. Just run `sudo apt install zygrib` in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @karel It's a suggestion/hint at best. The question is about other software and wine. I merely suggested what's logical and rational: Native software. But I don't even know how good or bad one or the other are.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to install a Windows program to view GRIB files in Ubuntu. You can install zyGrib GRIB file viewer in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu by running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install zygrib
```

The [zyGrib website](http://www.zygrib.org/) has animated samples that can be viewed at the website and also downloaded and opened in zyGrib GRIB file viewer locally to test if the application is working correctly. To change the weather map to a different day and time either click the forward/back arrows or move the slider under the weather map.